# PHP select option to change some data

Tags: php, select, wordpress

I am crating a wordpress plugin. Here I need some from someone. I have create a select box with php array look like:

```
$scmslidetype = array(
    "image_slide" => "Image Slide",
    "youtube_slide" => "YouTube Slide",
    "vimeo_slide" => "Vimeo Slide",
    "text_slide" => "Text Slide");
```

and my select box code is:

```
<select name="scmslidetype" id="scmslidetype">';
foreach ($scmslidetype as $key=>$value){
    $html .= "<option value='$key' ";
        if(isset($postdata['scmslidetype']) && ($key==$postdata['scmslidetype']))
        $html .= 'selected="selected"';
        $html .= ">$value</option>";
}
$html .=               '</select>
```

Select box is show fine. But I want when I select any value like Youtube Slide - My some table td is hide and some table td is show. How can I do this.

Comment: @karim ,If u want to show and hide the td on select change.Try the jquery onchange..

Comment: @user3040610 Thanks for reply. I have tried many way like change, onchange but not work. Can you please give me like example code?

Comment: @karim,try the code in the answer section..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below Code,

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#scmslidetype').on('change', function (e) {

  $('your-td-id').hide();

});

});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">                   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("select").change(function(){
$( "select option:selected").each(function(){
         if($(this).attr("value")=="youtube_slide"){
alert("This is Youtube slide"); 
}
         if($(this).attr("value")=="image_slide"){
alert("This is Image  slide"); 
}
         
});
}).change();
});
</script>

Comment: Above code is work only if page reload. Can you tell me how it work onclick or on select.

Comment: On  click ,try  with $('#scmslidetype').on('change', function (e) {});
On select,try with  $('#scmslidetype').on('click', function (e) {});